# Как удалить символы и буквы в preg_replace?

Tags: php

Привет, помогите пожалуйста удалить - /buyЦИФРА_

то есть где цифра тут может быть рандомное число. В конце символ _

```
// Проверяем наличие района
$proddist= preg_replace('#/buy#USi', '', $message); 
preg_match("/^([^_]*)_(.*)$/", $prodres);
$mestod = DB::$the->query("SELECT mesto FROM `sel_districts` WHERE `mesto` = '".$proddist."'  ");
$mestod = $mestod->fetchAll();

if (count($mestod) != 0) 
{   
$chat = escapeshellarg($chat);  
$message = escapeshellarg($message);    
exec('bash -c "exec nohup setsid php ./select.php '.$chat.' '.$proddist.' > /dev/null 2>&1 &"');
exit;
}
```

Вот как я убираю слово /buy как в этом сделать чтобы убиралось СЛОВО + Цифра + знак _

Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
$str = '/buy2$45_00000000/buy2$45_111111111';
$str = preg_replace('/\/[^\/]+_/','',$str);
echo $str; //00000000111111111
```

Comment: Не срабатывает(

Comment: У меня работает. Покажите полный текст для удаления и для чего вы это делаете. Иначе не понятно, что же там не срабатывает у вас. Когда все должно работать.

Comment: `/buy".$subcat['mesto']."_".$cat['mesto']."` это вывод сообщения телега бот. пример вывод будет таким /buy2_3 где 2 это категория а 3 подкатегория. Так вот чтобы сработало включение подкатегории нужно отправить просто цифру 3 но я вывожу не цифру а команду , тоесть /buy2_3. Так вот мне нужно удалить  /buy2_ чтобы осталась просто цифра 3

Comment: @Mike, хоспади, да что за каша у вас в голове. Мой пример рабочий. `$str = '/buy2_3';
$str = preg_replace('/\/[^\/]+_/','',$str);
echo $str; // 3` --- не вижу проблем, получили тройку.

Comment: Добавил полный код, посмотрите. Ну не срабатывает ваша регулярка(

Comment: @Mike, Опять байки, ну покажите как вы вставили мою регулярку и почему это не срабатывает? В упор не вижу, вижу костыли ваши.

Comment: `$proddist = preg_replace('/\/[^\/]+_/', '', $message); `

Comment: Посмотрите что приходит в `$message` - не своими словами, а `var_dump` - подозрение, что там не то, что нужно.

Comment: Спасибо все верно. Проблема с $message была

Answer (score 0):

тут можно проще решить строковыми функциями

```
<?php

$test = '/buy8989_';
$test = str_replace(str_split("/buy_"), '', $test);
var_dump($test);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9061a138e4856e182578cde8b03108d9280a5661

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$test = '/buy8989_';
$test = preg_replace("/(\/buy[0-9]*_)/", '', $test);
var_dump($test);
```